# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to create this model object but i keep getting this error:
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'.
Image of error is shared bellow.
I am using djangi 3.0.3
view.py file:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models
from django.views.generic import (View,TemplateView,ListView,DetailView,
                                    CreateView,UpdateView,DetailView)

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class SchoolListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'schools'
    model = models.School


class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'

class SchoolCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('name','principal','location')
    model = models.School
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("basic_app:detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy6HS.png)

Any help will be appreciable
Thank & Regards
Viplav Dube

Comment: Please, specify what exactly do you get and on which case

Comment: Sorry to pass incomplete information

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIIXx.png)If you are using path, in the urls.py in the application folder follow the code on the picture. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Hi Aman, please copy the code into the question, so people can help you directly, within StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error with your urls.py. Just make sure when you mention URL paths in your urls.py the definitive paths come first and variable paths come later. Here for instance, this code will give you an error:

```
path('<int:id>/' , view.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail")
path('create/' , view.CreateView.as_view(), name="create")
```

To avoid the error just change the order like this:

```
path('create/' , view.CreateView.as_view(), name="create")
path('<int:id>/' , view.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail")
```

This happens so because in the later piece of code django will look for path /create and if it is unable to match it then it will look for path int:id/. Now since int:id/ is a variable if django was to look for it first it would try to assign "create" to id variable which will give a validation issue.

Answer (score 0):

In **appurls.py** write this

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```